# Endless page with will_paginate not working with partial

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

I've been following the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised) on endless page and had previously done the same for will_paginate, but I'm getting errors however I try to implement it in my specific situation.  The will_paginate gems works perfectly, as does the jQuery call to the dom as far as I can tell from reading the developer tools in Chrome.  The issue is with what is being returned - rails doesn't like it.  Here's some code:

In `videos.js.coffee`:

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more videos...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

In my `views/users/index.js.erb`

```
$('.carousel').append(' <%= j render(@recently_added_video) %>');
<% if  @recently_added_video .next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@recently_added_video) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

In my shared partial, which is being rendered by `users/index.erb.html`

```
    <div class="carousel" %>

    <ul class="jcarousel-skin-recent">
        <% @recently_added_video.each do |v| %>
          <li><%= link_to image_tag(v.video_thumb(), width: 300), v %></li>
        <% end %>  
    </ul>
</div> 

   <%= will_paginate @recently_added_video %>
```

This gives me the following error from my development log:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 15ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial videos/video with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}.
```

So I then tried creating a `views/videos/_video.js.erb` partial with the same code as the `users/index.js.erb` file, but it then gives me the following error:

```
  Rendered shared/_recentlyadded.html.erb (853.8ms)
  Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (1741.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1813ms (Views: 1801.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.5ms | Sphinx: 0.0ms)
Illegal instruction: 4
```

and as you can see, it hasn't actually rendered the `_video` partial either.

In case it's of relevance, the instance variable `@recently_added_video` I'm trying to call is defined in the `application_controller` and works fine with the partial and `will_paginate`.

Can anyone help figure out what's going wrong?  Very confused!  Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind - I figured this out.

The problem was with this line

```
$('.carousel').append( ' <%= j render(@recently_added_video) %>' );
```

in the users/index.js.erb file.

I was following the railscast, but Ryan Bates has his instance variable set up to render a partial, so his code works, but because @recently_added_video isn't a partial and won't render one, it was returning the 500 error because there was no partial to find.

What I needed to do was actually render a partial like this:

```
 $('.jcarousel-skin-recent').append(' <%= j render ('shared/recentlyadded') %>');
```

Hope that helps anyone else who follows the railscast and has issues like I did.