# ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial pins/pin... + will_paginate infinite pagination error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I'm learning Ruby right now in an online course by making a Pinterest clone.

Trying to get infinite scroll to work, and getting errors in the console.

This isn't in the course, so I've been trying to follow this thread

[Endless page with will_paginate not working with partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961933/endless-page-with-will-paginate-not-working-with-partial)

I did everything the OP did in the thread, but for some reason I'm getting some errors when I scroll the page and also a 500 (Internal Server Error) when the next items are supposed to be loaded after scrolling down the page.

My in process project is here : http://clawomr-pinteresting.herokuapp.com/
If you scroll down you'll see the error.

And the code that I think is worthwhile to look at is here:

**pins.js**

```
$ -> 
$('#pins').imagesLoaded ->
        $('#pins').masonry
            itemSelector: '.box'
            isFitWidth: true

if $('.pagination').length # Thats for the Endless Scrolling
$(window).scroll ->
    url = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')
    if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        # What to do at the bottom of the page
        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more Pins...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

**pins_controller.rb**

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

def index
  @pins = Pin.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(7)

respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
...
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$boxes = $('<%= j render(@pins) %>')

$('#pins').append( $boxes ).imagesLoaded( function(){
  $('#pins').masonry( 'reload');
});
<% if @clips.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@pins) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

The Github source
https://github.com/cablecharlz/pinteresting

## Update:

Here's the error displayed on the server console

```
Processing by PinsController#index as JS
Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "_"=>"1389830140527"}
Pin Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "pins".* FROM "pins" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 7 OFFSET 7
Rendered pins/index.js.erb (4.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial pins/pin with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js,   :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
* "/Users/Charles/Desktop/pinteresting/app/views"
* "/Users/Charles/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views"
):
1: $boxes = $('<%= j render(@pins) %>')
2: 
3: $('#pins').append( $boxes ).imagesLoaded( function(){
4:   $('#pins').masonry( 'reload');
app/views/pins/index.js.erb:1:in   `_  app_views_pins_index_js_erb__4093603127232543635_2186204660'
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:14:in `index'
```

And the errors when scrolling

```
ce.event.dispatch application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:2
v.handle application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:2
ce.event.trigger application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:2
(anonymous function) application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:2
ce.extend.each application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:1
ce.fn.ce.each application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:1
ce.fn.extend.trigger application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:2
ce.fn.(anonymous function) application-3e70b62b8e586fea0e41235d8bbc0f00.js:3
(anonymous function)
```

Comment: "I'm getting some errors" is not very helpful. Include the errors (and stack trace) you are getting in the questions you are asking. Problems in your code will be easier to spot and people here will be more inclined to provide answers.

Comment: errors added, hope this helps

Comment: Also adding a screenshot of what I think should be the problem http://i.stack.imgur.com/RmbKm.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that much into Masonry, but I'll try to help. First I would recommend watching Ryan Bates' [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/114-endless-page-revised?view=comments) on endless scrolling with will_paginate. You can see the Github source [here](https://github.com/railscasts/114-endless-page-revised/tree/master/store-after).

The problem, as I can see it, is that you are not rendering your Pin-partial in your index view. You should do something like this:

**Index view**

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <%= render @pins%>
</div>
```

**_Pin.html.erb partial**

```
<div class="someclass">
 <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
 #pin code
</div>
```

It is important that your javascript matches the class and id names in the html.